# Xcode 6 wire IBOutlets Cocoa-Applescript

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, applescript, xcode6, applescript-objc

I'm trying to build a Cocoa-AppleScript app using Xcode 6 but I am unable to connect my IBOutlets dra. Specifically, I think I'm supposed to click and drag from IB to an AppleScript property i.e. 
`property theLabel: missing value` but that little circle icon to plug into via a ctrl-click drag isn't there! I'm worried that something is broken in Xcode 6, so hopefully I missed something.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put your label actually on the window, first of all.
You don't drag from the item to the script. You drag from the item to the delegate. Then, it'll give you a popup of the outlets you've define in the script. Select the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

when trying to drag it to the applescript, you acctually drag it to the "App Delegate" object on the app list and choose what you want to connect it to